# Can we get the HttpStatus Code error description in swift?

Tags: swift2

I am using Uber Api in my app. There is problem which occurs when I try to book a ride.I get a httpStatus 400 error. As per their documentation, this could arise due to a variety of factors.
[image]

How can I know through status code(Always"400") as to which description of given types causes it?.

My code now:

```
 if let httpstatuscode = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        {
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error : \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else if httpstatuscode.statusCode != 202 && httpstatuscode.statusCode != 409
            {

                print("Status Code\(httpstatuscode.statusCode)")

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    CommonViewController.alertViewUI("Alert", message: "Internal Server Error!")
                })

            }
            else if httpstatuscode.statusCode == 409
            {
               // self.getUberRideLive()
                print("Status Code\(httpstatuscode.statusCode)")
                CommonViewController.alertViewUI("Alert", message: "You are already on a ride!")



            }
```

Comment: Once you get error code `400`, you could check to see what caused the error. Use elimination technique to eliminate the possibilities (you had mentioned in your post). Check one by one and if you can't zero in on the error, you could have a default way of handling it. Example: Check if the email is confirmed and so on.

Comment: I have no experience with the Uber API, but according to https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/errors, the error response has  a JSON body with both machine and human readable error messages.

Comment: There are actually many status code.and each status code contain more than 1 description. How could i check it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `localizedString(forStatusCode:)` [method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse/1409741-localizedstring) from `HTTPURLResponse` [class](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse)

This is valid if you want to obtain descriptions for HTTP erros, if you want description from UBER errors you should look at JSON response from UBER operation.

Then, your code should looks like...

```
let message: String = HTTPURLResponse.localizedString(forStatusCode: httpstatuscode.statusCode)
```